Cox regression curves or Kaplan Meier?
Why not just present the survival curves from Cox cox survival regression analysis instead of Kaplan Meier curves?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why not indeed.  K-M estimates assume there are no risk factors, i.e., that survival time distributions are homogeneous within treatment groups.  Stratified Cox survival estimates allow you to adjust for risk factors, unlike KM.  Details are here.
